# When throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms is reached, is it treated separate failure to the actual failure strategies?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

It seems that when the `throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms` is reached the application is marked unhealthy and it stops consuming regardless of what failure strategy we set. So is this situation treated as a separate error to what the actual failure strategy is configured?

For example if we get a bad record that cannot be acked or nacked, the timeout happens and the application stops consuming. This makes it hard to deal with poison pills. If for example the failure strategy was dead-letter we could at least continue processing and go look at the dead letter topic and see the failed message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the throttled commit strategy does not nack messages. The `throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms` check is there to avoid a malformed stream that can't continue processing records and committing offsets, ex. a message that is not processed (not acked nor nacked) for a long time.

For poison pills, I suggest you detect them and nack the message (for example throw an exception). If that is not an option you can consider using the [Smallrye Fault Tolerance `@Timeout` annotation](https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance#adding-resiliency-timeouts)

Comment: So if we put a shorter `@Timeout` than `throttled.unprocessed-record-max-age.ms` that will nack the message before? We try to validate the message as much as we can. But you never know.

Comment: When using @Timeout does it also add a default retry processing? So If it times out will it also retry to reprocess the message based on what ever the default retry is?